# ARM template - CustomLinuxScript extension failure: Malformed status file (000003)Invalid status/status: failed

Tags: azure, arm, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template having 12 virtual machine resources. Each VM has 1 CustomLinuxScript extension resource associated with it.

Some of the CustomLinuxScript extensions fails with error: **Malformed status file (000003)Invalid status/status: failed**.

While some of them execute successfully. I deployed the same ARM template yesterday and none of them executed successfully. A few days ago all of them executed successfully. Does it seem like a bug in Azure?

Comment: care to share the template at least?

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/shaffan-chaudhry-confiz/e61fe03ef89a6b98a1eb20319f5fd31a

Comment: so what do the logs on the vm say? btw the template is horrible, you need to rework it, its completely unusable

Comment: This is the error:
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptForLinux'. Error message: \"Malformed status file (000003)Invalid status/status: failed\"."
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Actually there are a lot of resources in it. How can I improve it?

Comment: this is not the vm log error, this is the error that got propagated, you need to look at the vm extension logs, there are a lot of ways to improve it, say introduce loops, separate configuration from implementation, etc

Comment: Are you talking about vm activity logs ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you assume by activity logs, but I'm talking about vm extension logs https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript

Comment: I have seen extension logs at /var/logs/azure
I have figured out that there is a mistake in my shell scripts which is causing the failure.

Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer was to go to the VM extension logs and look at the errors to verify that the shell scripts were to blame

The overview of the extension:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript

near the of the document (readme.md) you can find where to locate the logs

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug in Azure. There is a mistake in my shell scripts which is causing this error.